# Background Thread And Foreground Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, background-thread

I have an monitoring application that will have multiple threads constantly monitoring the CPU usage, memory usage, hard disk usage, etc. I create a separate thread to monitor each of this and it keeps on running under the while loop get the values for the same.

Now my question is what happens if I keep `thread.IsBackGround = true` and what happens if I keep `thread.IsBackGround = false`?

I know the difference between foreground and background thread. But I am not able get what would be the better for me to use. If I have multiple foreground threads running then if I stop the application will all foreground threads stop automatically? or I need to explicitly stop them?

In case background threads, those will be aborted by the system.

Comment: Please define the method for stopping the application.

Comment: Sorry I dint get you. :-(

Comment: How is the application stopped? (Application.Exit(), closing threads, dropping AppDomain, windows message quit ...)
Is called by code or by user in what way

Comment: I think you'll find the answer after reading [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/40e97e/what-is-foreground-or-background-thread/). :-)